# Limit clause in sql injection

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, code-injection, clause

Can anyone explain to me why the limit clause in sql injection in some cases returns the first results by typing it like (LIMIT 0,1--) and in some other cases by typing it like (LIMIT 1,1--).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of sql are you talking about (e.g. SQL-Server, MySQL, Oracle etc)?

Comment: The version is MySQL.